# How do we suppress notification emails for events created through MS Outlook Calendar event REST API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office-js, office-addins, outlook-restapi, outlook-web-addins

We have an Office 365 add in for Outlook in which, events created in our system are pushed into Outlook through the MS Outlook Calendar Event API. Since we already send the participants - notifications when we create the event in our system, the subsequent push to Outlook Calendar through the API - also generates a similar such notification - causing all the participants to be notified again.

I wanted to check if there is a way to suppress these notifications during Outlook create Event calls - either through a property setting in the payload ("sendNotifications" : false) or through any general mailbox/Calendar setting at the user level or admin level.

Comment: Could you clarify the API(s) you are using in your Outlook addin to create the event?  Are you testing in Outlook desktop on Windows, MAC or Outlook on the web (OWA)?

Comment: We use the Calendar API Event create end point:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/calendar-rest-operations#CreateEvents

Our users are already using the add in on Windows Outlook, Mac Outlook and OWA platforms.

Comment: The add in is for integration with Oracle Engagement Cloud (OEC) and the event gets created via the task pane onto the OEC first before we push this also to Outlook calendar using the above REST API call.

Answer (score 0):

The Calendar API by design will notify attendees of new meetings and send updates to attendees for existing meetings. This is to ensure that all attendees have the same version (latest update) of the meeting.